# Nginx not redirecting http to https for subdomain

Tags: nginx

I have a subdomain (main domain is hosted on another server) hosted on a Linode instance. I wish to always redirect this subdomain to HTTPS.

Here's my /etc/nginx/sites-available/myconf

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name sub.example.com

    return 301 https://sub.example.com$request_uri; 
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name sub.example.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    root /var/www/production/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

        # With php-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

`nginx -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/myconf -t` outputs the following:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2018/02/01 22:52:40 [emerg] 6816#6816: "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/myconf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/myconf test failed
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong as this seems to work on other sites.

Thank you for any help!

EDIT: http version just shows the default nginx welcome page

Comment: Update: http version just shows the default nginx welcome page

Comment: Please post the output of `nginx -t`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems my issue was a missing `;` after `server_name sub.example.com`.